# Not able to identify the SIGSEGV Error in the code

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

You have been given an array A of size N consisting of positive integers.You need to find and print the product of all the number in this array Modulo 10^9+7.

**Input Format:**

The first line contains a single integer N denoting the size of the array. The next line contains N space separated integers denoting the elements of the array

**Output Format:**

Print a single integer denoting the product of all the elements of the array Modulo 10^9+7

**Constraints:**

```
1≤N≤10^3

1≤A[i]≤10^3
```

**Sample Input:**

```
5

1 2 3 4 5
```

**Sample Output:**

```
120
```

The code is working fine for the sample testcase but when I submit it on hackerearth it shows segmentation fault.I am unable to identify where the fault is.

I apologize if you find this a trivial question.

The code is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {   
    int i,N;
    int A[i];
    int answer = 1;
    cin >> N ;
    for(int i=0;i<=N-1;i++)
    {   
        cin >> A[i];
        answer = (answer*A[i])%(int)(1000000007);
    }
    cout << answer;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Main problem is here: `int A[i];`. How many elements do you expect `A` to be able to hold ?

Comment: N is the number of elements that we need to hold.

Comment: Run it through a debugger..

Comment: @A.Vik: OK - and how many elements do you think it is going to be able to hold, since you declared it as `int A[i];` ? (Hint: what value does `i` have at this point ?).

Answer (score 0):

You're just getting a stack overflow. `i` has undefined value and could be a very large value. Consequently the array is too big to fit in your program's stack address space.